# has_object_permission not being called at all in `(object)-detail` URLS

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a problem in that `has_object_permission()` gets ignored. Even when I access `http://127.0.0.1:8000/portfolios/3/` with the correct user logged in, it still defaults to `has_permission()`. Am I doing something wrong?

ViewSet class:

```
class PortfolioViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Portfolio.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.PortfolioSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsPortfolioOwner, )
```

Permission Class:

```
class IsPortfolioOwner(permissions.BasePermission):

    # Details
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        print("Checking for object")

        ruser = request.user
        if ruser is None:
            return False
        elif ruser == obj.client.user:
            return True

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        print("Checking for list")
        return request.user.is_superuser
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for `has_object_permission` to be checked, `has_permission` must return `True`. If it returns `False`, then permission checks will short-circuit and the request will be denied.

Your current permission class will only allow the user to view the list if they are a superuser. And an individual object cannot be viewed under they are a superuser *and* viewing the current user's object.